# Wagtail - customise FieldPanel to show results for current Locale

Tags: python, django, wagtail, wagtail-localize

I have a site which is i18n enabled and using `wagtail-localize`. When editing (or creating) the original language of a page, all the snippets show values for every language, if you use the standard `FieldPanel`. Using the SnipperChooserPanel is not an option because there are a lot of `ParentalManytoManyField`s in the model, it would be too cluttered for the editors.

[image: Screenshot 2022-07-29 at 15 07 59]

This is how the model and snippet is constructed.

```py
@register_snippet
class Level(TranslatableMixin):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Educational Level"
        unique_together = ('translation_key', 'locale')

class Activity(Page):
       ...
       level = ParentalManyToManyField(Level, verbose_name='Education level', blank=True)

        MultiFieldPanel([
           ....
            FieldPanel('level', widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple),
        ])
```

I'm trying to work out how to subclass `FieldPanel` so it uses the page's locale to filter the snippet queryset.

I have hacky/temporary solution to this using the `limit_choices_to` kwarg for `ParentalManyToManyField` but I can only filter by the user language not the page language.

```py
def limit_lang_choice():
    limit = models.Q(locale__language_code=get_language())
    return limit
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out the locale is lurking in the `BoundPanel.instance`

Here's a select panel that will filter according to locale. It'll match the default panel type for the field, or you can override with an appropriate form widget (one of `CheckboxSelectMultiple`, `RadioSelect`, `Select` or `SelectMultiple`). Set `typed_choice_field=True` to force `Select` into a dropdown widget (default is a list).

```
from django.core.exceptions import ImproperlyConfigured
from django.forms.models import ModelChoiceIterator
from django.forms.widgets import (CheckboxSelectMultiple, RadioSelect, Select,
                                  SelectMultiple)
from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _
from wagtail.admin.panels import FieldPanel


class LocalizedSelectPanel(FieldPanel):
    """
    Customised FieldPanel to filter choices based on locale of page/model being created/edited
    Usage: 
    widget_class - optional, override field widget type
                 - should be CheckboxSelectMultiple, RadioSelect, Select or SelectMultiple
    typed_choice_field - set to True with Select widget forces drop down list 
    """

    def __init__(self, field_name, widget_class=None, typed_choice_field=False, *args, **kwargs):
        if not widget_class in [None, CheckboxSelectMultiple, RadioSelect, Select, SelectMultiple]:
            raise ImproperlyConfigured(_(
                "widget_class should be a Django form widget class of type "
                "CheckboxSelectMultiple, RadioSelect, Select or SelectMultiple"
            ))
        self.widget_class = widget_class
        self.typed_choice_field = typed_choice_field
        super().__init__(field_name, *args, **kwargs)

    def clone_kwargs(self):
        return {
            'heading': self.heading,
            'classname': self.classname,
            'help_text': self.help_text,
            'widget_class': self.widget_class,
            'typed_choice_field': self.typed_choice_field,
            'field_name': self.field_name,
        }

    class BoundPanel(FieldPanel.BoundPanel):
        def __init__(self, **kwargs):
            super().__init__(**kwargs)           
            if not self.panel.widget_class:
                self.form.fields[self.field_name].widget.choices=self.choice_list
            else:
                self.form.fields[self.field_name].widget = self.panel.widget_class(choices=self.choice_list)
            if self.panel.typed_choice_field:
                self.form.fields[self.field_name].__class__.__name__ = 'typed_choice_field'
            pass

        @property
        def choice_list(self):
            self.form.fields[self.field_name].queryset = self.form.fields[self.field_name].queryset.filter(locale_id=self.instance.locale_id)
            choices = ModelChoiceIterator(self.form.fields[self.field_name])
            return choices
```

So in your Activity class, you'd call this with

```
LocalizedSelectPanel(
    'level', 
    widget_class=CheckboxSelectMultiple, 
    ),
```

Comment: This is a great answer! It works flawlessly. Its worth noting that I had to upgrade to at least Wagtail 3.0.2  to get the `BoundPanel` functionality.

Comment: Glad it worked! Yeah, sorry, should have mentioned BoundPanel only came in with Wagtail 3.x. This solution won't work with orderables - a new orderable instance has no locale attribute and no reference back to the parent clusterable object. Solution to that is similar but needs a slightly hacky reading the URL to grab either the locale (for new instance) or parent ID (if it pre-exists).